# Restrict the user to not open more than 1 jframe in java swing

Tags: java

I have a jtable from which I'm picking up which column the user has clicked and showing one jframe respectively

```
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)Table.getModel();
int col = Table.columnAtPoint(new Point(evt.getX(), evt.getY()));
if (col == 14)
{
  new frame2(name).setVisible(true); 
}
```

`name` is a string which I'm passing from (current frame) frame1 to a new frame (frame2). This set up works without any problems, just that if i click twice, I see two frame2 opened. Is there a way to disable multiple openings of frame2.

Comment: Disable the button when you create the 2nd JFrame, and enable the button when you exit the 2nd JFrame.  I'd guess the users of your application won't like this.

Comment: I gave this a thought, the problem is the button is in frame1. I can disable it on click easily. But how do I re-enable it. I checked adding button.setEnabled(true) to the formWindowClosed event of frame2. but the button variable is not recognized

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try this:

```java
if (!frame2(name).isVisible()) {
    new frame2(name).setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: I tried a similar approach, but throws an error. Not able to understand where I'm missing. "Cannot Find symbol method frame2(String)